# Can I require confirmation on all destructive operations on a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have a local MySQL database I'm playing with manually. I can use the `safe-updates / i-am-a-dummy` options to disallow unqualified delete statements:

```
DELETE FROM table;
```

However, I can still easily lose everything with an accidental

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table;
```

as this latter statement is not prevented by `safe-updates`. Apart from backing up the database, what's the best way to prevent data loss here? Is there some way to require confirmation before *all* destructive actions, not just delete?

Comment: Define destructive. How is query parser to know what delete is intended and what is not?

Comment: After your first accident typing the word `TRUNCATE` even in a Word document will make you twitchy. Self-correcting! Just wait until you have to use [the `TRUNCATE()` math function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) in MySQL. That's a scary day. :-p

Comment: Best way to prevent data loss is the use of permissions, revoke the drop permission to the user so truncate is not posible and you will need to switch to another user with enough permissions to really truncate the table.

Comment: @PerroVerd I wouldn't say mysql is stellar in the permission and flexibility category.